# find ids with a specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn JavaScript, and I wanted to change what I am working on into a pure JavaScript solution. How do I change this to JavaScript:

```
var hrefs = $("a[id^=a_l_]").map(function() {
  return this.href;
}).get();
```

It basically finds all id's containing "a_l_" and puts it into an array.

Here is what I have tried

```
var matches = [];
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
  if (elems[i].id.indexOf("a_l_") == 0)
  matches.push(elems[i]);
  console.log(matches);
}
```

Comment: @therefromhere sorry forgot my code. i updated post.

Comment: on the face of it that code looks OK - what's actually happening with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first do a filter, then do a map.

```
var hrefs = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"), function(node) { 
  return node.id.indexOf("a_l_") === 0;
}).map(function(node) {
  return node.href;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Always use brackets `{}` for conditions! Else soon or later you will make mistakes!

```
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].id.indexOf("a_l_") == 0) { // <-- {
        matches.push(elems[i]);
        console.log(matches);
    }                                       // <-- }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find all elements with id equal "a_l_" and add them to an array. I suggest you shouldn't have the same id for your html elements. You should move them to class. Anyway, try this:

```
var matches = [];
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
  if(elems[i].id.indexOf("a_l_") != -1) {
    matches.push(elems[i]);
    console.log(matches);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ES5 array methods (use a shim / polyfill if they don't exist)

```
var hrefs = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function(el) {
    return el.id.indexOf('a_l_') === 0;
}).map(function(el) {
    return el.href;
});
```

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Zu3dJ/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution in pure Javascript, working on modern browser (`IE8+` included)

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("a[id^='a_l_']");
```

`elems` is a collection of `<a>` elements whose `id` are starting with `a_l_`. Indeed `querySelectorAll` is slower but readability is hugely increased